# Detecting that a removable drive will be ejected (before ejecting) in order to close open file handles

Tags: winapi

My delphi application opens a drive handle to a removable drive. The handle is needed to receive file changes via ReadDirectoryChangesW. 
The handle is opened with:

```
CreateFile(PChar(fFilePath), FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY or GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE or FILE_SHARE_DELETE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS or FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);
```

If I try to  remove the drive via 'Safely remove hardware' in the system tray I receive a message dialog: 'Windows cannot stop the your device because a program is still using it'.
I tried listening to change events like WM_DEVICECHANGE, DBT_DEVICEREMOVEPENDING, DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE or similar to get information about a pending eject operation but this seems to be too late since the dialog is displayed before these events are fired.
Is there an event which is triggered right before this dialog is displayed. Or are there any other options to detect that an USB drive should be removed?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried [`WM_DEVICECHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/devio/wm-devicechange) with [`DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/devio/dbt-devicequeryremove)?

Comment: Yes, I tried that but it seems to be too late. The first WM_DEVICECHANGE message that I receive is triggered after the message dialog in Windows has been displayed.